# MySQL table creation error #1064

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I use phpMyAdmin for managing my databases and tables and I am having issues importing a (large) sql file that I generated from a CSV. This is the top of the file:

```
  CREATE TABLE universities(

     id     INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY 

    ,name   VARCHAR(122) NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO universities(id,name) VALUES (0,'Paul Mitchell the School-Huntsville');
INSERT INTO universities(id,name) VALUES (1,'Southeastern School of Cosmetology');
INSERT INTO universities(id,name) VALUES (2,'Paul Mitchell the School-Birmingham');
```

The error:
[image]

I have another table, almost identical, called mesh that uploaded fine.

Any help would be awesome, thanks!

Comment: you are missing 'cr' when you executing your create table statement.you are only selecting 'eate'.  Look at your error you carefully you will find solution.

Comment: Why would phpMyAdmin not read the "cr" when I can plainly see it is all correct in the sql file?

Comment: May be when you are executing script you missed to select 'create'  . Hence you are getting this error.

Comment: Can you try editing a copy of your SQL file to remove all the INSERT statements and try just the CREATE TABLE portion?

Comment: Also, how exactly are you trying to upload the SQL file? Are you using the Import tab? What phpMyAdmin version do you have?